# Android - how to access database from within onClick()

Tags: android, sqlite, onclick

In my android application I can access the SQLite database just fine, EXCEPT from within an onClick() function, and I cannot figure out why.  There are no exceptions and no messages in logcat, I'm not sure where else to look for errors.  I'm almost sure it's a context error of some sort, but I'm stumped on how to debug it.  Can anyone give me some hints?

I'm relatively inexperienced with android so please be kind, but here is some code that represents what I'm doing:

```
public class DBAccessClass {
    private SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    private Context context;

    public DBAccessClass(Context c){
    context = c;
    }
    public void initMyDB(){
      mydb = context.openOrCreateDatabase("myapplicationdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

    public Cursor someQuery(){
      Cursor rows = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable", null);
      return rows;
    }
}

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

  public DBAccessClass dbAccess;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    dbAccess = new DBAccessClass(this);
    dbAccess.initMyDB();   

  }

  .....

  @Override
  public void  onClick(View v){
    Cursor rows = dbAccess.someQuery();  // <<<------ I get no rows here, no data, no error!! 

    SQLiteDatabase anotherTry = openOrCreateDatabase("myapplicationdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor otherRows = anotherTry.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable", null); // <<<< No data and no error here either!     

  }

  public void someOtherFunction(){
    Cursor rows = dbAccess.someQuery();  // <<<------- I DO get data here! 
  }


}
```

Comment: That code is incomplete. How exactly are you trying to read from the cursor?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The cursors are empty, I can see it in the debugger.  This is from a much larger project, we're accessing the database the same way in many many other places and it works fine, inside this onClick() is the only place it's not working so it definitely has something to do with being inside that onClick().  I can write an entire demo app if necessary to reproduce it (I can't post the real app for several reasons), but I was hoping the code above was enough to explain the problem.